# Как отключить окно OUTPUT в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При изменении файла открывается окно(вкладка) `Output`. Кто знает, где отключить данную фичу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже. у вас настроен какой-то file watcher. Проверьте **Settings | Tools | File Watchers** - есть ли у Вас там какие-то вотчеры? если есть, попробуйте их удалить или отключить

Comment: Спасибо большое.